# Error message TypeError: this.subQuery is not a function appears

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeorm

If I run the tests with jest, I got always the error message `TypeError: this.subQuery is not a function` with a reference on the marked line in the testModelDb.test.ts file

tests/jest.setup.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({ path: './.env.test' });
```

.env.test

```
TYPEORM_CONNECTION=sqlite
TYPEORM_DATABASE=:memory:
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE=true
TYPEORM_LOGGING=false
TYPEORM_ENTITIES=dist/models/**/*.js,modules/**/entity/*.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS=dist/services/db/seeding.js
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_RUN=true
```

src/models/test.model.ts

```
@Entity()
export default class TestModel {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    @Column()
    name!: string;

    @OneToMany(() => OtherModel, (other) => other.testModel)
    otherModels!: OtherModel[];
}
```

tests/testModelDb.test.ts

```
describe('Integrationtests', () => {
    let connection: Connection;

    beforeAll(async () => { connection = await createConnection(); });

    afterAll(() => connection?.close());

    beforeEach(async () => { await connection.synchronize(true); });

    describe(`functions`, () => {
        describe(`#function1()`, () => {
            test('Test 1', async () => {
                await connection
                    .createQueryBuilder()
                    .insert()
                    .into(TestModel) // <- here
                    .values([ {name: 'Test item 1'} ])
                    .execute();
              
                expect(true).toBe(true);
                
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

In connection configuration, make sure you added the entity name in the `entities:[]` config property.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solve removing a forgettable datasource instance of Typeorm in my code, let me explain:

this is my ormconfig:

```js
import 'dotenv/config'
import { DataSource } from "typeorm"
import { Users, Wallet } from "../entities"

const datasource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    entities: [Users, Wallet],
    migrations: [__dirname + "/migrations/*{.js,.ts}"],
})

datasource.initialize();

export default datasource;
```

but in my code, I didn't instantiate this script properly

```js
import { Wallet } from '../entities';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'
import { IWalletRepository } from '../interfaces/wallet-repository'
import datasource from '../config/ormconfig'; // <---I imported my ormconfig 

export class WalletRepository implements IWalletRepository{
  AppDataSource: DataSource // <-- but I didn't passed here
  async get (userId: Wallet['user_id']): Promise<Wallet> {
    return this.AppDataSource
    .getRepository(Wallet)
    .createQueryBuilder('wallet')
...
```

I solved that just passing my ormconfig to AppDataSource

```js
  AppDataSource: DataSource = datasource
```

I hope it helps